# Android Studio xml preview closes automatically

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, preview

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3. While clicking on the UI components in the xml code the preview window closes automatically. Again while selecting on the preview, the window appears and again when select the xml code the window disappears. Is there any fix available?

Answer (score 7):

Enable pinned mode and docked mode by right click on preview from left of window.

**OR:**

Select the Preview Window > Go to Window menu > Active Tool Window > Docked mode

Comment: There is no such option in the preview window

Comment: Select the Preview Window

Go to Window menu > Active Tool Window>Docked mode

Comment: In Android Studio 3.2 (Beta 4 at least) if you right click the Preview window “toolbar” and uncheck “docked”, the option disappears and you have to open it again, and go to Window -> Active Tool -> Docked like this answer says. The option to dock is there, it just disappears when you select any other mode (floating, split, or Window). ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I had to select a different option ("docked") to then have "pinned" enabled.